# What does Windows Authentication authenticates in IIS? Can I disable Anonymous Authentication in my case?

Tags: php, authentication, iis, windows-server

I have an internal PHP app (only for the employees using the domain network) running on IIS with Anonymous Authentication.

The way users are logging in to the app is via a login form (username and password).

That's why I disabled Windows Authentication and only enabled Anonymous Authentication.

But now there was a request to be able to save failed login attempts and the user that failed. For that I wanted to get the actual Windows user that is trying to connect.

In one of my other apps I am using Windows Authentication so I know I can get the Windows user using PHP's `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];`

So, I wanted to add that ability on this app and I enabled Windows Authentication as well. However, when both Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication are enabled, `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];` returns an empty string.

Then, I disabled Anonymous Authentication and voila! it showed me the Windows user. And also, the login form kept working, i.e., the user still needs to put his username and password.

So I got confused - How does Windows Authentication works? What exactly does it authenticate? Since there is no password or anything, it just gives me the Windows username.

Do I now basically have "two layers" of authentication? The "server" level authentication via the Windows Authentication, and the "app" level authentication (the login form)? (But then again, what exactly does the Windows auth do?)

Can I safely leave the Anonymous Authentication disabled then?

Comment: `What exactly does it authenticate`...it just ensures that the request comes from a logged-on Windows users which is valid on that domain, and is not anonymous, or somehow from outside the domain. It checks their credentials against Active Directory records. You can read a lot more about it online quite easily, including in-depth explanations of the process it follows. It's also sometimes known as Kerberos Authentication.

Comment: `Can I safely leave the Anonymous Authentication disabled then`...assuming you don't need/want anyone who's not a valid domain user to access your application, then yes.

Comment: `Do I now basically have "two layers" of authentication`...yes. You might want to consider whether the form-based authentication process is actually necessary, if you can automatically identify a user from their AD account, without them needing to type anything to your application, or remember any extra usernames and passwords etc. Essentially it's a form of SSO (single sign-on), albeit one which only works within a Windows domain.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-authentication-overview, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-authentication-overview

Comment: Wow thank you, awesome explanation, everything is understood now! The reason I want to leave it with a login form is because it was requested that the session is timed so after certain period of inactivity time users must re-login. What confused me more was that I found an article saying that it's NOT only against AD users. But, looks like they were wrong. That was really helpful. thanks again

Comment: `it was requested that the session is timed so after certain period of inactivity time users must re-login`...I wonder what useful purpose anyone thinks that serves, in an intranet environment. It will just annoy users, mainly :-).

Comment: `I found an article saying that it's NOT only against AD users`...what else did it say you can authenticate against instead, then? I guess in theory it might be able to talk to a generic LDAP server, but AFAIK that's not how the implementation in IIS works.

Comment: To be honest, I only read the title from the results on Google and just kept looking for other answers until I thought I'd get better answers here (which I did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What exactly does it authenticate...

It ensures that the request comes from a logged-on Windows user which is valid on the same domain as the IIS server, and is not anonymous, or somehow from outside the domain. It checks their credentials against Active Directory records. You can read a lot more about it online quite easily, including in-depth explanations of the process it follows.

In IIS you can configure a site to use Kerberos (the default) or NTLM behind the scenes to provide the actual authentication mechanism.

> Can I safely leave the Anonymous Authentication disabled then...

Assuming you don't need/want anyone who's not a valid domain user to access your application, then yes.

> Do I now basically have "two layers" of authentication...

Yes. You might want to consider whether the form-based authentication process is actually necessary, if you can automatically identify a user from their AD account, without them needing to type anything to your application, or remember any extra usernames and passwords etc. Essentially it's a form of SSO (single sign-on), albeit one which only works within a Windows domain.

Some useful references to get you started:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-authentication-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-authentication-overview

Comment: Windows authentication != Kerberos authentication. Thus, you cannot say Windows authentication is SSO. Typical mistakes.

Comment: @LexLi technicall that is true, but in the context of IIS the terms are often used interchangeably, which is what the OP is likely to come across. Kerberos is of course just one of the mechanisms IIS supports for doing web authentication with Windows users, NTLM being the other one but which is pretty much deprecated as far as I understand, and not recommended. Can you suggest a better way to word my answer? I'm more than happy to amend it.

Comment: You can simply explain what is challenged based authentication and how domain controllers participate and eliminate the needs to send passwords from the browser to IIS. NTLM is weaker but never "deprecated". Since Kerberos is complex to configure properly, a lot of places have NTLM in use (whether they realize it or not). At least you should remove Kerboros and SSO sentences from this answer.

Comment: @LexLi why, in your view, can't it be described as SSO? You log onto to the operating system, once, and then from there you can sign into any web app which supports the scheme, without providing your credentials again. To me, that's pretty much what "single sign on" means, in practice. There are of course many other ways to implement the same concept, so unless you are thinking of a narrower definition of SSO, I'm struggling to see why that would be the wrong thing to say.

Comment: NTLM requires a lot of re-authentication and it also falls short when credentials need multiple hops. So, it is not recognized as one of the SSO solutions. With that in mind, calling Windows authentication an SSO can be a mistake. I don't see there is a need to answer the questions above by adding SSO either.

Comment: @LexLi I've never (in 20+ years) worked anywhere where NTLM was actually in use in IIS (except as the fallback option which is never actually called upon), or where using Kerberos was a problem, it seems to be very standard to set up in a modern windows domain. Perhaps I have not experienced a more heterogenous environment where it might be more useful, or something, I don't know. So in practice, from my experience, that's effectively a non-issue, but that could just be anecdotal. And presumably NTLM isn't _designed_ to require multiple re-auths...it's just a bit old and c**p?

Comment: I supported IIS at Microsoft and then served as IIS MVP for a decade, so I believe talking about experience of an individual isn’t a meaningful way to move discussions forward. I left comments here for the future readers, not for you.

Comment: @LexLi I'm not doubting your credentials. If you feel you can make a better answer, please go ahead and add one. If you're going to criticise mine, it would really help if you could be more specific and engage with the discussion, instead of being dismissive. That isn't constructive for other readers either. e.g. If what we're talking about isn't "SSO", then how would you describe it instead? Because clearly it's a step up from individual application logins. I'm trying to learn here, for me, and to make a better answer. Just saying it _isn't_ something is not actually going to move us forward.

Comment: @LexLi Also I have already re-worded the answer somewhat to what I hope is a better reflection of the scenario. If you still disagree with the changes, it would be beneficial to know why. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

> Offering an alternative answer without the typical mistakes in understanding Windows authentication.

1. You cannot leave anonymous authentication on when you want to enable other IIS authentication methods like Windows/Basic/Digest (all three are challenged based authentication). That's because anonymous authentication takes highest priority when on, and the browsers won't be challenged for other methods.
2. You can authenticate your users using different methods, such as Windows authentication on IIS and forms based authentication in your PHP code. However, if they both verify the same AD user credentials, you don't get any extra protection.

   > For more protection you should use two/multiple factor authentication approaches.
3. To understand what is Windows authentication, which is rather complex, you'd better talk to your domain administrators and also study very specific materials (like IIS/AD books). Microsoft has something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-authentication-overview) to get you started but you can easily get lost. In short, since a domain controller participates in the Windows authentication process, the browser does not need to send explicit user password but a security token to IIS. Once receiving the token, IIS knows which user it belongs to and your PHP code knows that too.

> I rather not talk about Kerboros/NTLM/SSO at this stage, as you won't easily digest them without fully understand the above.